# Is it important to declare <!DOCTYPE>

Tags: html

So my question is , is it important to declare  and why is the word "DOCTYPE" always in caps? Is there any specific reason for it to be mentioned in an Html code , since without it the code just seems to run fine.

Comment: what have you researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Google will solve more than 95% of your early questions into coding ;)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#HTML_4.01_DTDs
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition

The short summary:

HTML is a subset of XML (eXtensible Markup Language) with specified tags. In XML you can use a wide range of custom tags (called elements) like

```
<price value="10" currency="euro"></price>
```

So to bring order and consistency we need to declare types and tell the software reading it what sort of document it is and how to process it.

The reason it is in caps is just for the software to recognise: Here it tell me what kind of doc it its.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp 
"he  declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in."